# export particular rds schema from one aws region to another region

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench

I have one RDS(MySQL) DB server us-west-1 region and one RDS(MySQL) Db server in ap-south-1(Mumbai), Now I want export particular schema(not whole DB's) from us-west-1 region rds to ap-south-1 region rds server. Could you please advise how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a tool like `mysqldump` to export the schema you want, and then manually copy that to the other region and import it into the other database. RDS doesn't support copying a single schema, only entire database snapshots.